# Error in ic_launcher_background.xml file in drawable, whenever new project is opened in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

In my previous project there was no such problem, also the `ic_launcher_background.xml` file was different.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/snackbarStyle"
    class="com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```

> error not well-formed

Comment: You should edit your question and add your error

Comment: Make sure you do not have any spaces or tabs before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` Also I think it should be View, and not view, but i assume you must've changed it for this question

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
  style="?attr/snackbarStyle"
    class="com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout"
```

the code will be like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
```